# How to understand broken wing butterfly option strategies?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, greeks

I feel very confused about the greeks analysis for the broken wing butterfly strategy.

Let's say for the stock ABC, we enter into a such strategy: we long a put option with strike $k_1$ and another put option with strike $k_3$，and at the same time short two put options with strike $k_2$, where $k_2-k_1>k_3-k_2$.

Then what I read tells me that this position is possibly a net debit or a net credit when starting with. Intuitively, if $k_1$ is too low, then the strategy should be a net credit. Intuitively, if the stock price is above $k_3$, the $\Theta$ should be positive since I profit from time decay. At expiration all puts will become worthless. But if $k_1$ is not that low, I can imagine it would be a net debit position when entering, then the $\Theta$ would be negative since I will lose money from time decay.

How to understand such behavior of this strategy. And another confusion is, if I enter the strategy with net debit, I will have two break even price; but if I enter with net credit, I will have only one. This also seems strange to me. So what determines if I enter with debit or credit, and how to understand the behavior of this strategy? Thank you so much!

Comment: although it uses no math, I found this article useful https://tickertape.tdameritrade.com/trading/unbalanced-butterfly-strong-directional-bias-15913 especially the idea of starting from a butterfly (which we already understand) and adding a vertical spread to "move" one of the legs away. So a broken butterfly (bbf) is a combination of two things: bf+vertical spread.

Answer (score 0):

> Intuitively, if $k_1$ is too low, then the strategy should be a net credit.

That is an incorrect conclusion.  The lower that $k_1$  is, the larger the credit will be or the lower the debit cost will be.  Bear in mind that $k_3$  also affects cost.  The deeper ITM it is, the more it costs, and vice versa..

> ... if I enter the strategy with net debit, I will have two break even price; but if I enter with net credit, I will have only one. This also seems strange to me. So what determines if I enter with debit or credit, and how to understand the behavior of this strategy?

The distance of  $k_1$  and  $k_3$ from $k_2$ determines the cost of the respective legs.  The further away from $k_2$ they are, the less $k_1$  costs and the more  $k_3$ costs.  The more that  $k_3$ is ITM, the greater its cost, eventually exceeding $k_2 - k_1$, resulting in a debit spread.

IOW, if the spread credit is greater than $k_3 - k_2$, there is no upside risk and there is only one break-even.

I can't help with your theta question since I only use delta in my hedging.  The rest of them are Greek to me.